# Add new contact to primary account

Tags: contacts, accounts, nokia-lumia-930

When I first set up my Lumia 930, I used my private Micorosft account. Afterwards, I also added an Exchange account (to get my work e-mail).

When I want to add a new contact on my phone, it will add it to the Exchange account and not to my private account. Also, I cannot find an option to change this.

Am I missing something here? Can I choose the account to which I want to add a contact to?

Comment: How are you adding the contact? Are you going in through the people hub?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to `People` and tap the `+` button. On top of the page it shows `New Ventigrate Contact` (Ventigrate being the name of my employer and Exchange account).

Comment: @Abbas Please don't use backticks for highlighting words. If you need to add emphasis to some words, use bold formatting instead. See [this meta post](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/254/1401) for more information. Thanks!

Comment: Odd; My phone gives me the option to choose where to save the contact. It may be worth checking with your employer, in case it is a policy they've enforced via ActiveSync (although it's not an option I'm aware of)

Comment: @Indrek: I'm sorry, I dodn't know about this. I'm mostly on StackOverflow and I use it a lot there. :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm not aware of any enforcement. I'll check again if I see an option somewhere as to where I want to save the contact.